# Chrome process from Selenium dotnet wont start in Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

im using Selenium webdriver in asp.net web api and this code works locally but in production when deployed it says chrome process wont start.
Webdriver.exe is in wwwroot deployed, and it has the same version as Chrome. Here is the code

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
           
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("--headless");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920x1080");
options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", "Downloads");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", false);
 
string chromeDriverPath = @"C:\Users\Gentrit\source\repos\Azon\Azon\bin\Debug\net8.0";

using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, options)){
    // The error is thrown here, cant create chrome process
}
```

I've made all changes to the code, selenium is updated, ive made a copy of chrome.exe and published it in wwwroot and made a reference to its path as binary location, nothing seems to work
Here is the full error

```
[Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer: Connection ID "18014398527467168636", Request ID "4000237f-0004-fa00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)at Azon.Controllers.HomeController.UploadImageAsync(IFormFile image) in C:\Users\Gentrit\source\repos\Azon\Azon\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 100at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Program.<>c.<<<Main>$>b__0_10>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Gentrit\source\repos\Azon\Azon\Program.cs:line 151--- End of stack trace from previous location ---at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

Comment: is it actually an issue with the environment being production? You could setup ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development as a quick test.

It also might be helpful to provide the full error message with stack trace :)

Comment: i havent tried that, im checking if it works when the app is published in azure service
you can check the whole error up there, ive just added it

Comment: I tried my best to format the code in your question, but the exception message and stack trace is completely unreadable.

Comment: Is Google Chrome installed on the machine running this code in production?

Comment: @GregBurghardt no its isnt. Should i perhaps add google chrome to azure in some way and reference it because the project is deployed there.

Comment: You need Google Chrome installed. ChromeDriver is an adapter that allows you to control Google Chrome remotely. ChromeDriver is not the browser itself.

Comment: I have it in pc, on the correct path with the correct version, as i said the code works locally but not in production, i still havent found a solution :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by creating a virtual machine in azure and installing all the needed dependencies.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).